# Find the largest $n\in \Bbb{N}$ answering the following terms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $$f(x) = -\frac{1}{12}x^4 + o(x^5)$$

Also, Let $$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} &\mbox{if } x\ne 0 \\
C & \mbox{if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

I need to find the largest $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that there's $C\in\Bbb{R}$ so $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Now, I think $n$ can be arbitrary large and then, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$. If we choose $C=0$ then $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Unfortunately, I'm wrong and the answer is $n=4$.

Why?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=-x^4/12$ and $n=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is large, then $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}$$ will not be $0$. For example, if $f(x) = -\frac{1}{12}x^4 + 0$, the limit is $0$ for $n<4$, is nonzero for $n=4$ and does not exist for $n>4.$

Comment: Got it. So, $C=-1/12$. Thanks